# How to pass arguments to a JXCore native application?

Tags: jxcore

I created a NodeJS application and I used JXCore with the `-native` flag to produce a stand alone `.exe`.
Now I'm trying to run the application and to pass some command line arguments.

It is working fine with the NodeJS app but not with the `exe`:

```
c:\project> node MyApp.js -arg1 bla
OK.
```

Works fine. But

```
c:\project> jx package MyApp.js MyApp -native
c:\project> MyApp.exe -arg1 bla
Error, please provide argument arg1.
```

I went through the documentation about [packaging](http://jxcore.com/docs/jxcore-feature-packaging-code-protection.html) and some [blog posts](http://jxcore.com/turn-node-applications-into-executables/) about the same. I am not able to find how to do it. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: I just tried without the `-native` flag to produce a jx package. The command line arguments are passed correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's exactly the same but there is a minor difference for compiled apps. For the command line below;

> jx myapp.js arg1 arg2

The process arguments are;

`process.argv == [ 'jx' , 'myapp.js', 'arg1', 'arg2' ]`

When you compile myapp.js into myapp.exe, you would simply call;

> myapp.exe arg1 arg2

hence the process arguments would be;

`process.argv == [ 'myapp.exe', 'arg1', 'arg2' ]`

You may use a trick in order to switch easily between compiled or non-compiled apps;

```
if(process.IsEmbedded) process.argv.unshift(process.argv[0]);
```

So, for a compiled app, the result would be: `[ 'myapp.exe', 'myapp.exe', 'arg1', 'arg2' ]`, with `arg1` and `arg2` located at the same indices as when it is run using `jx` (non-compiled).